# Can't pass 'const pointer const' to const ref

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, constants, pass-by-const-reference

Suppose you have a set of pointers (yeah...) :

```
std::set<SomeType*> myTypeContainer;
```

Then suppose that you want to search this set from a const method of SomeType:

```
bool SomeType::IsContainered() const
{
    return myTypeContainer.find(this) != myTypeContainer.end();
}
```

This doesn't work. The `this` ptr in the method is a `const SomeType *const`, which I can't put into the `find`. The issue being that `find` takes a const-ref, which in this case would mean that the passed pointer is treated as const, but not the thing it points to.

Is there a way to resolve this smoothly (without changing the set template type)?

Comment: Upgrade to C++14: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find (see 3 or 4)

Comment: @Caleth … and change the `Compare` type accordingly, e.g. `std::set<SomeType *, std::less<>>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you said, in the const member function `this` becomes `const SomeType *` (i.e. pointer to const), it can't be implicitly converted to `SomeType *` (i.e. pointer **to non-const**), which is the expected parameter type of `find`.

You could use [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to perform explicit conversion.

```
bool SomeType::IsContainered() const
{
    return myTypeContainer.find(const_cast<SomeType *>(this)) != myTypeContainer.end();
}
```

It would be safe if the cast result is not used for modifying; while [`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) won't do that.

Comment: @songyanyao I think that using a `const_cast` is not necessary, there is a smoother alternative that I describe in my answer.

Comment: Nitpicking: the type of `this` is `const SomeType*` (not a const pointer).

Answer (score 16):

In order to enable "mixed" comparison in an ordered container, you can use a `key_compare` type that declares the typename `key_compare::is_transparent`.

The default comparison functor class of set is `std::less<Key>`. It is not "transparent". But `std::less<void>` is "transparent" and performs the comparison of any arguments `a` and `b` as long as `a<b` is well formed. So you could define your own comparison functor type or you could use `std::less<void>` (or equivalently `std::less<>`):

```
set<SomeType*,std::less<>> myTypeContainer;
```

---

Comment: Both solutions have advantages and disadvantages of their own. I accepted the answer above because it solves the issue in my particular case. Thank you for providing an alternative!